# TypeORM ddl always enclosed in double quotes

Tags: oracle, orm, ddl, typeorm

I am trying to use TypeORM with an oracle 12c database and ran into a very frustrating issue.
When any table is created using typeOrm it generates the table and column names as strings (enclosed in double quotes).  This makes it very frustrating to write any SQL queries on the generated schema as everything is now case sensative and I have to define an alias for every column if I do't want the double quotes to show in the output.
Is there any way/option to force typeORM to not enclose any DDL in double quotes?  Hibernate doesn't do this so seems very strange that typeORM does this by default.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle database is case sensitive on its own - "foo", "Foo" and "FOO" will be three different tables/columns. Therefore TypeORM escapes all table/column names by default and there is no option to disable this escaping.

Comment: Why does Hibernate not have to escape the DDL in an oracle DB but typeOrm has no alternative?  I understand that Oracle is case sensative however I still don't understand why everything must be enclosed in ""